# Making Geofence more accurate using location manager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

Im developing app that alert user when entering and exiting geofence.but its not very much accurate and not fast when im using it without mobile data or wifi. so i thought about updating location manager using timer every few seconds. will that be helpful to accurate geofence?

Note(Alternative way) :  i tried without using geofence. specific location and my current location with location manager and get the distance. its more accurate than geofence. but the problem is its not working when app is killed.

```
 CLLocationManager* locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *myLocation = [locationManager location];


    float longitude=myLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    float latitude=myLocation.coordinate.latitude;


            CLLocation *officeLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[location.latitude floatValue] longitude:[location.longitude floatValue]];
            CLLocation *NewLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
            CLLocationDistance distance = [officeLocation distanceFromLocation:NewLocation];


        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: You're encountering a common issue with `CLLocation`. You can constantly ask for location and keep it going when app is in background to some extent but it destroys battery and user permission issues. Happy coding!

Comment: check out this tutorial about keeping location updating alive while in background [link](http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7)  another one about Region monitoring [link](http://mobileoop.com/ios-region-monitoring-and-location-manager#comment-446)